# Implement methods for trait without additional traits

Tags: rust

Looking for "blanket" implementation of the method(s) for trait.

Let's say for a trait

```
pub trait A {
  fn do_a(&self);
}
```

want to have `boxed` method that wraps with box, without introducing any additional traits:

`fn boxed(self) -> Box<Self>;`

I can have another trait to achieve that ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bba9a867db51a0cce332fed679baf330))

```
pub trait A {
  fn do_a(&self);
}

pub trait Boxed {
  fn boxed(self) -> Box<Self>;
}

impl<T> Boxed for T
where
  T: A,
{
  fn boxed(self) -> Box<Self> {
    Box::new(self)
  }
}
```

However, new trait `Boxed` is required for that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this falls under rusts philosophy of explicitness. When importing a trait, it should be clear from the trait definition all methods that trait exposes. Any mechanism to add methods to a trait outside its definition breaks that rule.

Comment: Can you not add `boxed()` directly to `A`?

Comment: You can create `boxed` as a free-function, but you wouldn't be able to use it like a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `boxed` directly to `A` with a default implementation so that structs won't need to implement it themselves:

```
trait A {
    fn do_a(&self);
    fn boxed (self) -> Box<Self> 
    where Self: Sized 
    {
        Box::new (self)
    }
}

struct Foo{}

impl A for Foo {
    fn do_a (&self) {
        todo!();
    }
    // No need to redefine `boxed` here
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo{};
    let _object: Box<dyn A> = foo.boxed();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=564138b30f6e77ba3cf119fd22f6ea11)

Comment: Yes, default implementation [can be added directly to a trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#default-implementations), however the scope of using such trait will be limited, i.e. it can't be used as a `&'a dyn A` form: "A cannot be made into an object: for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically"

Comment: @tmDDWCzr You can avoid that by adding a `where Self: Sized` constraint *only* on the method like is shown in [this answer](/a/53989780/15710392).

Comment: @tmDDWCzr See amended answer